# Cloudfront and s3 gzip giving conflicting results

Tags: amazon-s3, gzip

I've tried to add gzip encoding to a static website which is deployed on AWS with s3 and cloudfront.  However the assets don't appear to be gzipped properly.
If I test via curl with: `curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' https://www.example.com` I don't get the `content-encoding: gzip` header in the response. However testing with chrome dev tools (with the cache disabled gives back the header also the assets size indicates they aren't being compressed. (testing the site for gzip also fails when checking via `https://www.giftofspeed.com/gzip-test/`)

In cloudfront the 'compress objects automatically` option has been selected and in s3 the bucket policy has added the option to allow Content-Length header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Content-Length</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was found in the assets not being tree shaked correctly. The assets were actually being gzipped correctly.